# Connection to Hyper-V using openwsman without "basic" authentication?

Tags: hyper-v, wsman

I'm trying to test WS-MAN capabilities to manage multiple hypervisors (mainly ESXi and Hyper-V); in terms of Hyper-V, all samples I come across insist on first tuning the Hyper-V authentication to "basic"; does anyone know if this is a shortcoming in current OpenWSMAN implementation or by design it can't support other authentication mechanism OR please correct me if my understanding is wrong :-).

System Details:
Host OS: SL 6.1
OpenWSMAN: 2.2.0 (client version)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an explanation for above observation. On linux, OpenWSMAN uses OpenSSL for authentication connections, now OpenSSL on Linux supports "digest" and Windows machines does not. Windows supports Kerbos/GSSAPI which is not currently supported by OpenSSL.

Thanks!